# bootstrap navbar dropdown not working nothing happens when clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>wordpress theme practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">subMenu1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">subMenu2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">subMenu3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">subMenu4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>  
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="text_search" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="btn_search" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the head part.. i declare another script src because im thinking that it cannot see the js file and also it was suggested on an another post. when i click the li labeled dropdown.. nothing happens.. sorry for this post. ive been trying to figuring this out and its already a day. googled it already and tried the given solution. but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

first you only need a css style of bootstrap in your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

before the  add the js files

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

and the nav code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="page.html">Pages</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cine <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

in your firebug see if the styles and scripts charge on the site

Comment: put this on head <script src="<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")%> " type="text/javascript"> </script>